# Merge two untracked folders with Git

Tags: git, version-control

Until now our team worked against two *copies* of the same project source, one for live and one for testing. In some instances sloppiness meant that the live version had fixes that weren't applied to the development copy.

I now want to merge both into a single Git repository and start doing strict/sensible version control with the project source. I know the solution is going to by highly handraulic, but:

What's the best way to merge two separate directories of source into a single Git repository, when neither represents a specific branch of the other?

Comment: please explain to me as someone who has some knowledge of git branches but no knowledge of your project, why the live and testing editions of your project should not be modelled as branches in git.

Comment: They will be, this is achieved by @Thomas answer then after the merge a fresh test-dev branch can be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this process, and it seems to work:

```
git init .
cp -r /dir/one/* .
git add .
git ci -m'Commit directory one'
```

So now we have directory one on branch `master`. Do the same for two, creating a new branch that doesn't share history:

```
git checkout --orphan two
git rm -rf .
cp -r /dir/two/*
git add .
git ci -m'Commit directory two'
```

Then just merge as usual:

```
git checkout master
git merge two
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with `git`, can you state which dirs I should be in for various commands? You say "we have directory one on branch `master`" but you do an init then copy directory one to CWD. This implies we've created another directory and not made a git repos out of the actual dir one at all...

Comment: Correct. You copy both dirs into your repository. All these commands are executed in an initially empty directory, which becomes your git repo.